# Submit Livy Pyspark job with python driver in remote server

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, livy

I am trying to run a POST /batches command through Livy with the following configurations:

```
{
    'files': ['some.pex'], 
    'file': 'script.py', 
    'conf': {'spark.pyspark.python': '/directory/some.pex'}
}
```

The command works as long as the `/directory/some.pex` is on the local spark machine. Is there a way to host the `some.pex` on a remote location (ie. hdfs, http server, etc) or have it pull the files from the directory to which `--files` is uploaded?